# Google play store shows my app incompatible

Tags: android, android-studio, app-store

**minSdkVersion 15
compileSdkVersion 23**

I Searched my app in Desktop PlayStore Website For my device Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 SM-T211 Android Kitkat 4.4.4. But it shows this app is incompatible for your smartphone or tab? But Some of the other apps which i had created with same min and max version shows in PlayStore and i can able to install it also.

What could be the problem? Can any one give me the solutions for this?

Comment: Please post your `Manifest.xml` here.

Comment: Your app's android version is greater than your tab's android version

Answer (score 1):

Please check AndroidManifest file permission for this issue may be your device not support some of your requested permission (like phone call, contact or camera)

```
<uses-feature
  android:name="string"
  android:required=["true" | "false"]
  android:glEsVersion="integer" />
```

in your manifest